# What does "[self data][date]" mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, casting, mbcalendarkit

Can any one just tell me what the below code in iOS mean? Its a piece of code from `MBCalendarKit`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *data;

- (NSArray *)calendarView:(CKCalendarView *)calendarView eventsForDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    return [self data][date];
}
```

How does the above function return an `NSArray` when the global data is an `NSMutableDictionary` and the local date is `NSDate`?

And what does `[self data][date]` mean?

Comment: Maybe something to do with short-hand synhtax: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `data` is an `NSDictionary` then it means exactly the same thing as `[data objectForKey:date]`. That syntax [was introduced a couple of years ago](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html) — ideally read the whole thing but if in a hurry then jump to 'Object Subscripting'.

Comment: Interesting syntax, definitely creates a WTF moment which is not a good thing. For readability/understandability it would be best to use a different syntax or an intermediate for `[self data]`. Even `self.data[date]` would be an improvement.

Comment: As a side note, using an NSDate as the key here is valid because you can use any id<NSCopying> (an object that conforms to the NSCopying protocol) as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks.. the syntax is now clear. But in this case does the NSDictionary is casted to NSArray?

Comment: It makes more sense if you name you dictionaries appropriately. Something like `self.dataItemsByDate[date];`

Comment: @LeoJoseph There is no casting going on here. Many languages support dictionary access with the square brackets.